# Getting error while npm start in react js

Tags: reactjs, node.js, npm

when i run react app using npm start it compiled successfully  , but when i done any mistake in my code , the server get crashed with this error .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdSez.png)

webpack compiled with 1 error
node:internal/buffer:961
super(bufferOrLength, byteOffset, length);
^

RangeError: Array buffer allocation failed

trying to start npm start , and getting error message

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**First Method:**

1. Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`.
2. Run `npm install`.

**Second Method:**

1. In the Terminal, run `set NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096`.